# Accessing thymeleaf fragments from controller

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

Hi I am new to thymeleaf . While I was trying to access thymeleaf fragment from my controller it says that the fragment or template does not exist.Below is my controller code for accessing my fragment.

### controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/firstpage")
public String firstPage(){
  return "mainpage::firstpage";
}
```

### My thymeleaf interceptor file is

```
public class ThymeleafLayoutInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
private static final String LayoutFile = "mainHTML/layoutFile";
private static final String ReturnedHtmlFile = "returnedHTML";

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if (modelAndView == null || !modelAndView.hasView()) {
        return;
    }

    String originalViewName = modelAndView.getViewName();
    if (originalViewName.startsWith("redirect:") || originalViewName.startsWith("forward:")) {
        return;
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName(LayoutFile);
    modelAndView.addObject(ReturnedHtmlFile,originalViewName);
}
}
```

### and my spring configuration file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class BeanConfig {
@Bean 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean 
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}
@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}
}
```

### my layout file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <body>
<div th:include="${returnedHTML}" class="contents"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

### and finally my mainpage.html file

```
<html>
<body>
  <div th:fragment="firstpage">
   Hi...This is my first page 
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

when i return string just as "mainpage" in controller all the contents of main page appears.But if we try to access as fragment it returns the above mentioned error message.Can anyone help me solve my problem here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you have done everything right.

I think the problem is the way org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardIncludeFragmentAttrProcessor (in fact org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor) tries to resolve the fragment before evaluating the expression: ${returnedHTML}. And since the string "${returnedHTML}" does not contain the fragment yet, the template will not be handled correctly.

See org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.computeFragment(Arguments, Element, String, String): List

When you don't swap variables in the interceptor and return a fragment from a controller, it will work like a charm. I assume you implemented a custom layout technique similar to the one described here: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/thymeleaf-template-layouts-in-spring.html. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah..I've tried only seeing that blog..Is there any proper way for accessing the fragments from the controller using custom layout?

Comment: Due to the reason I described, I think it is hard to achieve. What would definitively work is: <th:include="${viewName} :: ${fragmentName}">. But I think implementing this will be more problematic than using Layout Dialect, that is in fact quite easy to work with.

Comment: Thanx Rafal.Lemme try the layout dialact then.